Вывод ошибки в использование библиотеки random
У меня 907 строчный код, но скину код, в котором эта ошибка (проблема с рандомом):
import random

import time as t

trophis = 0
trophis2 = 0
obs = trophis + trophis2

while True:
    Start_voproc = int(input("\nВаших общих трофеев:" + obs + "\nВы желаете сыграть (1)10 игр или (2)50 игр или (3)100 игр, или же (4)хотите поменять персонажа? Выберите цифру для этого:\n"))
    #############################!1111111111111111
    if Start_voproc == 1:
        print(f"\n\nВаши трофеи: {trophis}\n")
        spc = input("\n1) Одиночное столкновение (+10/ -13)\n2) В парное столкновение(+9/ -12)\n В режим 3 на 3(+8/-12)\n4)Дуэли(+3/-3)\n(для выбора нажмите на цифру из представленных трех для выбора режима на 100 игр):\n") 
        game = 10
        if spc == "1":
            for _ in range(game):
                print("Хорошо, начинаем ", game, "игр")
                if trophis >= 0 and trophis <= 49:
                    onewar = random.randint(0, 10)
                    res = onewar + trophis
                    trophis = res  
# и так далее

ошибка составляеться в этом:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\т\Desktop\python\игры\Игра brawl stars.py", line 9, in <module>
    Start_voproc = str(input("\nВаших общих трофеев:" + obs + "\nВы желаете сыграть (1)10 игр или (2)50 игр или (3)100 игр, или же (4)хотите поменять персонажа? Выберите цифру для этого:\n"))
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

помогите пожалуйста, как исправить

Какая ошибка-то?

= RESTART: C:\dekstop\test1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\т\Desktop\python\игры\Игра brawl stars.py", line 9, in 
Start_voproc = str(input("\nВаших общих трофеев:" + obs + "\nВы желаете сыграть (1)10 игр или (2)50 игр или (3)100 игр, или же (4)хотите поменять персонажа? Выберите цифру для этого:\n"))
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str


obs + поменять на + str(obs) +

